# Euler–Lagrange for cabin on a Ferris wheel - solution with special function

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am looking for a special function which solves the equation of motion of a cabin on a Ferris wheel.

The e.o.m. reads

$$ \ddot{\phi} + a \, \sin\phi + b \, \sin(\phi - \tau) = 0 $$

with

$$ a = gl^{-1}\Omega^{-2} $$

$$ b = Rl^{-1} $$

$$ \tau = \Omega t $$

$R$ is the radius of the wheel, $\Omega$ is its angular velocity. $l$ and $m$ are length and mass of the pendulum representing the cabin. $\tau$ is the dimensionless time, derivative is w.r.t. $\tau$.

Does anybody know an exact solution of this diff. eq. in terms of special functions?

Comment: You can try solving this with Mathematica.

Comment: not now, not on my iPad ;-)